# transforming PDEs into ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm looking at these equations in $u(x,t)$ and $v(x,t)$
\begin{equation}
u_t=u_{xx}+(1-u-v)u=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v_t=v_{xx}+(1-u-v)v=0
\end{equation}
the paper I'm looking at claims that setting $u(x,t)=u(\alpha)$ and $v(x,t)=v(\alpha)$ with $\alpha=x+ct$, these become
\begin{equation}
u_{\alpha\alpha}-cu_\alpha +(1-u-v)u=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v_{\alpha\alpha}-cv_\alpha +(1-u-v)v=0
\end{equation}
I can see that this makes sense, but for some reason I can't prove it. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you recall the multidimensional chain rule from vector calculus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a big deal. Just use the following chain rules. Consider $f(x,t)$ is a function of independent variables $x$ and $t$, define $\alpha  = x + ct$ and $g(\alpha ) = f(x,t)$ hence by chain rule one can obtain

$$\left\{ \matrix{
  {{\partial f} \over {\partial x}} = {{dg} \over {d\alpha }}{{\partial \alpha } \over {\partial x}} = {{dg} \over {d\alpha }} \hfill \cr 
  {{\partial f} \over {\partial t}} = {{dg} \over {d\alpha }}{{\partial \alpha } \over {\partial t}} = c{{dg} \over {d\alpha }} \hfill \cr}  \right.$$

and hence you can obtain by the above relations that

$$\left\{ \matrix{
  {{{\partial ^2}f} \over {{\partial ^2}x}} = {{{d^2}g} \over {{d^2}\alpha }} \hfill \cr 
  {{\partial f} \over {\partial t}} = c{{dg} \over {d\alpha }} \hfill \cr}  \right.$$

Finally, you may just put these into your equations.